# how to remove border in OutlinedButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble when I want to remove the border on the OutlineButton

```
 OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text('Pext Page'),
 )
```

please help me!!

Answer (score 13):

Try below code hope its help to you.

**Using transparent border color**

```
  OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('Outlined button'),
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      side: BorderSide(
         color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

**Using none border**

```
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    side: BorderSide.none,
  ),
  child: const Text('Outlined button'),
),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Or you can used TextButton also

```
 TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('Text button'),
  ),
```

Your result screen using TextButton-> [image]

Comment: You should be able to replace `BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)` with `BorderSide.none` with the same effect.